# Global Namespace Alias (double colon) with curly brackets in comment - C#

Tags: c#, namespaces, comments, curly-braces, global-namespace

I want to call some method in curly brackets in a comment, for example like this:

```
$"{global::Company.Company.Helpers.Method()}_{Parameters.ProcessName}";
```

But in this situation everything behind the colon become a comment. Is there a way to use double colon in curly brackets in comment in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely due to the way that string formatting works - `{thing:A}` will format `thing` with `"A"` as format information. For example, formatting an enum as `{myEnumValue:D}` will use the integer value, but `{myEnumValue:G}` will use the name of the enum value.

You can work around this by wrapping the colon-containing expression in parentheses, like so:

```
$"{(global::Company.Company.Helpers.Method())}_{Parameters.ProcessName}"
```